# Intellisense for KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2012

I've installed the RC of VS12 Update 1 expecting to light up Intellisense for Knockout as describe by John Papa via: http://www.johnpapa.net/knockout-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012/#comment-59581.

Because I'm working with Razor:

```
@if (false)
{
     /// <reference path="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>    
}
```

No joy. There are a number of different Nuget packages devoted to Knockout - is that coming into play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a reference to */scripts/_references.js*?  One way or another, I think you would still need a */// ref* for the knockout file. And make sure you are working with an MVC4 project.

Comment: I'd tend to agree that references are needed but I'm not seeing any specific step-by-steps anywhere. Papa's article shows the results but nothing specific as to how to get there.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything, any MVC4 project should include /Script/_references.js.  Open it and be sure your current Knockout file is listed there.  NOTE: if you update a JS file through NuGet, it will not update the _references file. More info here: http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/

Comment: I'd missed that the 'MVC4 Project' requirement.